# how to display data with *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, object, ngfor

i trying to display data with *ngFor, but for some reason this doesn't display any data, and any error.

I already tried alot of samples that i found in internet, none of those worked so i decide to ask here.

here is what i have: 
ts file:

```js
  public querySuccess: any[];


  this.userService.getMentions().subscribe(
  (returnAPI) => {
    this.querySuccess = returnAPI.data;
  });
```

my html:

```
<div *ngIf="returnAPI">
  <div *ngFor="let key of querySuccess">
    <div>{{querySuccess.firstName}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!returnAPI">
    <div>0 results found!</div>
</div>
```

the `getMentions().subscribe()` return this Json:

```
    {
    total: 3,
    data:[
    {userId: 0, firstName: "test", lastName: "xzy"},
    {userId: 0, firstName: "john", lastName: "yeet"},
    {userId: 0, firstName: "jamal", lastName: "abc"}]
    }
```

Comment: firstName is a property on the key here. Try {{ key.firstName }}

Comment: And, try changing this `let key of querySuccess` to this `let key of querySuccess.data`.

Comment: @ndoes does not work

Comment: @R.Richards dont work too :/ 
when I console.log (this.querySuccess) out of subscribe it returns a empity array

Comment: Your returnAPI api's scope is inside subcribe method.
remove that if condition ,it will work

Comment: thx for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that if condition to loop that ngFor.If its to show that no data error message use **querySuccess** because returnAPI does not seems to defined anywhere.

```
 <div *ngIf="querySuccess">
  <div *ngFor="let key of querySuccess">
    <div>{{key.firstName}}</div>//key is single istance queryselector is full array.
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!querySuccess">
    <div>0 results found!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
<div *ngIf="returnAPI">
  <div *ngFor="let key of querySuccess">
    <div>{{key.firstName}}</div>  <!-- key instead of querySuccess -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would firstly recommend you put your code in a function like

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllQueries();
}

getAllQueries() {
    this.userService.getMentions().subscribe(
        (returnAPI) => {
            this.querySuccess = returnAPI.data;
         return this.querySuccess;
   });
}
```

make sure you call this in the ngOninit function or your constructor

Comment: Hey! thats already inside a function, this function is called when i search something in ion-search bar using (onChange) property

Comment: Ooh carefully gone through the code. @Nambi is right, key is the instance for calling the looped data